# Visualizing modular elliptic curves

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, complex-geometry

Domain coloring refers to pictures of analytic functions made by letting the function pull back a well--chosen simple color scheme from the range to the domain.

If an elliptic curve is modular, then one has a nice map, in steps, from the upper half-plane...to a modular curve...to the elliptic curve...to the complex plane (this last by, say, by the Weierstrass $\wp$-function or its derivative).

Has anyone made pictures of the upper-half plane thusly colored...for visualizing modular elliptic curves?

Comment: [Cremona](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/staff/J.E.Cremona/book/fulltext/chapter2.pdf) is computing the degree $d$ of the map $F:X_0(N) \to \Bbb{C/\Lambda_f}$ given by $F(i\infty)=0, dF=2i\pi f(z)dz$, $f$ a rational newform, $\Lambda_f$ is the lattice $F(\gamma(\infty))-F(\beta(i\infty))$. Let $U$ be a connected fundamental domain of $X_0(N)$ (ie. $[\Gamma_0(1):\Gamma_0(N]]$ copies of $|\Re(z)|<1/2,|z|> 1$) look at $B=\{ u\in \overline{U},\exists z\in \partial U, F(u)=F(z)\}$, then $\overline{U}-B$ has  $d$ pieces, each mapping biholomorphically to a fundamental domain of $\Bbb{C/\Lambda_f}$